# Call a Method of a class under other package

Tags: java, android

I am try to return String 'terCd' to other package.

But, my app crash.

error message is

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.switchdata, PID: 10870

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

at tercodecomponent.TerCode.getTerCode(TerCode.java:25)

at com.example.switchdata.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

---

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.switchdata;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


import tercodecomponent.TerCode;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TerCode t = new TerCode();
        String s = t.getTerCode("TERNAME");
        Log.i("i", s);



    }
```

TerCode.java

```
package tercodecomponent;

import android.content.Context;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class TerCode extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String getTerCode(String iptname){
        Context context;

        String json = "";

        String terCd = "";
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("jsons/terData.json");  //jsonfile in assests
            int fileSize = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSize];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();


            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject res = jsonObject.getJSONObject("res");


            JSONArray array = res.getJSONArray("NAME_LIST");

           for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                String terName = object.getString("trml_Nm");
                String terCode = object.getString("trml_Cd");

                if (iptname.equals(terName)) {
                    terCd = terCode;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return terCd;
    }
}
```

how can I see 'Log.i("i", s);'?

Comment: `extends AppCompatActivity` - why?

Comment: is `TerCode` an activity? If not why extending `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: i want to use getAssets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be extending `AppCompatActivity` unless `TerCode` is an Activity. Remove `AppCompatActivity` extension and send you `context` of `MainActivity` to `getTerCode` method. And then use `getAssets()` method.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.switchdata;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


import tercodecomponent.TerCode;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TerCode t = new TerCode();
        String s = t.getTerCode(getApplicationContext(), "TERNAME");
        Log.i("i", s);
}
```

TerCode.java

```
package tercodecomponent;

import android.content.Context;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class TerCode {

    public String getTerCode(Context context, String iptname){

        String json = "";

        String terCd = "";
        try {

            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("jsons/terData.json");  //jsonfile in assests
            int fileSize = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSize];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();


            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject res = jsonObject.getJSONObject("res");


            JSONArray array = res.getJSONArray("NAME_LIST");

           for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                String terName = object.getString("trml_Nm");
                String terCode = object.getString("trml_Cd");

                if (iptname.equals(terName)) {
                    terCd = terCode;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return terCd;
    }
}
```